# Python, how to get the actual file location

Tags: python, file, path

Using python 3: How do I get the path of my files?
Please check the code below:

```
path =r'\\Desktop'
os.chdir(path)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for txt_file in files:
        if txt_file.endswith(".txt"):
            txt_fileSh=txt_file.rstrip(".txt")
            path_txt_file=os.path.abspath(txt_file)
            print(path_txt_file)
```

What I get is

```
\\Desktop\a.txt
\\Desktop\b.txt
```

...
What I should get:

```
\\Desktop\Fig1\a.txt
\\Desktop\Fig2\b.txt
```

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change directory. You can build the full path based on the root of the *walk* as follows:

```
path = r'\Desktop'
import os

for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) for `abspath` states that:

```
os.path.abspath(path)

Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path. On most 
platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function normpath() as follows: 
normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path)).
```

So, you are actually just joining your `path` with the filename.

You want to use the path to the current directory instead, which is the first of the three items returned by `os.walk`, the one you named `root`.

So, just replace

```
path_txt_file=os.path.abspath(txt_file)
```

with

```
path_txt_file = os.path.join(root, txt_file)
```